# Page reload redirect user to the home page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react-redux`. Here what I want to do is, when user clicks on the page reload,,that time I am getting one message `that Changes that you mage may not be saved`. SO, here, after this , when I click on the reload page I want to redirect user to the home page. So, currently this is not happening. So what I am doing is ,

```
history.push({
    pathname: '/quiz-questions',
    state: {
        isReload: false
    }
})

On click of button, redirecting user to this page .


Now, In the component.

class FetchedQuestionComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("props are", props);
        this.onUnload = this.onUnload.bind(this);
    }

    onUnload(event) {
        console.log("calling this", event);
        event.returnValue = "Hellooww";
        return "Hellooww";
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload)
        this.props.disableJob();
        this.props.questionChangeModeFalse();

    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload)
    }

    render() {

        if (!this.props.criteria.Low[0].technology) {
            return <Redirect to='/' />
        }
        //Other part rendering
    }


}
```

Now, Here what is happeing, it is always redirecting this on the home page if it comes from another page.as well.